# do I need to bind the edges of a remnant if it has carpet pad attached on the underside?

Tags: carpet

I recently purchased a carpet remnant to use as an area rug in my living area.  The carpet remnant that I purchased has the carpet pad already attached to the carpet.  My living area currently has wood laminate flooring.  So the remnant is on the laminate flooring.  Since it is a remnant the edges are unfinished.

My question is, do I need to 'bind' the edges of the remnant since it has the carpet pad attached on the underside?  To me it seems like the pad would hold the carpet together and not cause the edges to fray or shed.

Any thoughts/ advice would be more than helpful.

Comment: Duplicate of http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11220/should-i-bind-the-edge-of-an-unbound-remnant-rug-if-so-how-do-i-do-so ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the carpet has an attached underlay this will not keep the edges from fraying. You will need to have the edges finished. Your carpet will last longer and look better.